# jenkins no trigger build remotely option

Tags: jenkins

I ran a jenkins instance by docker container which is build by its latest version(1.642.2).

I follow the instruction:

`docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins`

But there is no `trigger build remotely` option.

I googled for a while and installed plugins such as `Build Authorization Token Root Plugin` and `Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin` but there still no `trigger build remotely` option when I create a new project.

What should I do?Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to activate "security" to have this trigger show up. 
You can configure it at "Jenkins" -> "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure Global Security"

Users also need anonymous read access to be able to trigger a build.